# What is the most appropriate data structures for these cases?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, priority-queue, heapsort

I am working on a program and I'm considering which data structure is most appropriate.

I have the following class -

```
public class item{ 
    String name;
    int value;

    public item(String name, int value){
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have two cases -

To store a large amount of items and retrieve the top n amount of items while new items are being added and old items have their values updated.

To store all the items and retrieve top n amount of items without any new items being added or old items being updated.

I'm trying to achieve the best case time complexity for both cases.

I have thought about storing all items in a map for look up by their name, and in a maxheap, then removing n number of items from the top, storing them, then adding them back to the stack.

I've looked at priority queues and binary search trees as options, would either of these be more suitable? or are they any other structures that would fit either of these cases?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "top n amount of items"?

Comment: If I want to retrieve the top 100, 50, 20 items by value

Answer (score 0):

If name is unique you can use IDictionary. It is pretty fast for this uses

Comment: It's not particularly fast in getting the top k items. You end up having to sort and then select.

Comment: You cant have both fast sorting and fast access with unique name. You can use Linq sort on IDictionary value, or you can use IList for faster sorting. Or you can implement resorting when you add or remove new elements on list, as sorting is faster if list is already mostly sorted.

Comment: But a heap paired with a dictionary will give you O(log n) insertion and removal, O(1) lookup, and O(n log k) retrieval of the top k elements. Just the dictionary gives you O(1) insertion, deletion, and lookup, but O(n log n) retrieval of the top k elements. Binary tree is somewhere in the middle.